# Calendar Plus by Bamboo not showing items

Tags: list, sharepoint, calendar, bamboo

I would like to ask if you have any idea on why Bamboo Calendar Plus on Sharepoint is not showing my list?(It was working recently but then the data disappeared) I was able to select the list by providing the site URL, and configure the settings on Data Source tab.

Tried with other lists it works but this specific one doesn't.

Hope you can solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed, my list was already on its threshold. Removed previous items and it showed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).